# git push origin HEAD:ref/for/master creates a new commit everytime instead of amending previous changes

Tags: git, gerrit

This question is related to the git/gerrit push command

When I submit my changes to the git/gerrit with the following command

```
git commit
git push origin HEAD:ref/for/master
```

It creates a commit.

Now if I want to amend any changes(creating a patch ).
I modify the file and uses the following command

```
git commit --amend
git log
```

It amends the detail in the same previous commit

But when I try to push it to the remote master with the following command

```
git push origin HEAD:ref/for/master
```

It creates a new gerrit commit instead of creating a patch for the previous commit

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git commit --amend works, but, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357187/is-it-possible-to-add-patch-sets-to-a-gerrit-review-without-ammending-squashing#comment11987820_6448020):

> you need to add the gerrit `change-id` at the bottom of your commit message (`Change-Id: 234j243rasdf...`) right before the git #'ed commit description and the change will be patched onto your previous commit –

See more about Change-Id in the [Gerrit documentation](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/Documentation/user-changeid.html).

### Change Upload

> During upload by pushing to a `refs/for/*` or `refs/heads/*` branch, Gerrit will use the Change-Id line to:
>
> - **Create a new change**:
>     If this is the first time it has seen the Change-Id mentioned in the commit message, Gerrit will create a new change for review.
> - **Update an existing change**:
>     If Gerrit has seen this Change-Id before, but has not yet seen this new commit object, Gerrit will add the new commit as a new patch set on the existing change.
> - **Close an existing change**:
>     If Gerrit has seen this Change-Id before, and the commit is being pushed directly into a branch, the existing change is updated with the new commit, and the change is closed and marked as merged.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, also I have checked that the `gerrit` change Id remains same in all my commits. However `gerrit` shows them as different commits. Even `git log` shows the only commit I have made.

Comment: @darth_coder OK, try and ask a  new question (with the details specific to your situation, in particular the version of gerrit, git, the OS used)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use git commit --amend --no-edit
Without --no-edit it will alter the message, checksum and you will end up having a new commit id.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the true command to create a patch for the previous commit is:
git push origin HEAD:refs/**changes**/

for example:
git push origin HEAD:refs/**changes**/1234

To get the commit's gerrit code, you need to login to gerrit and find your commit in "My -> changes" menu, the commit's gerrit code will appear at the end of the link in the address bar of the browser, for example, with below link:
http://10.207.215.71:81/#/c/**5678**/
the gerrit code will be "**5678**"